# Error in str.contains Panda custom function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column that has a lot of doctor specialties. I want to clean it up and created a function below:

```
def specialty(x):
    
        if x.str.contains('Urolog'):
            return 'Urology'
        elif x.str.contains('Nurse'):
            return 'Nurse Practioner'
        elif x.str.contains('Oncology'):
            return 'Oncology'
        elif x.str.contains('Physician'):
            return 'Physician Assistant'
        elif x.str.contains('Family Medicine'):
            return 'Family Medicine'
        elif x.str.contains('Anesthes'):
            return 'Anesthesiology'
        else:
            return 'Other'

df['desc_clean'] = df['desc'].apply(specialty)
```

However I get an error `TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable`

There are too many values to use a manual mapping so i wanted to use str.contains. Is there a way to do this better?

EDIT: Sample DF

```
{'person_id': {39063: 33081476009,
  50538: 33033519093,
  56075: 33170508793,
  36593: 33061707789,
  51656: 33047685345,
  95512: 33022026049,
  40286: 33038034707,
  3887: 33076466195,
  40161: 33052807819,
  52905: 33190526939,
  35418: 33008425164,
  35934: 33015737122,
  3389: 33055125864,
  136: 33139641318,
  105460: 33113871389,
  52568: 33075745388,
  24725: 33052090907,
  34838: 33205449839,
  31908: 33183672635,
  36115: 33006692696},
 'final_desc': {39063: 'None',
  50538: 'Urology',
  56075: 'Anesthesiology',
  36593: 'None',
  51656: 'Urology',
  95512: 'None',
  40286: 'Anesthesiology',
  3887: 'Specialist',
  40161: 'None',
  52905: 'Anesthesiology',
  35418: 'Urology',
  35934: 'None',
  3389: 'Ophthalmology',
  136: 'Rheumatology',
  105460: 'None',
  52568: 'Urology',
  24725: 'Family Medicine',
  34838: 'None',
  31908: 'Nurse Practitioner',
  36115: 'None'}}
```

Comment: can you provide a sample of your dataframe?

Comment: maybe df.sample(n=20).to_dict() or something

Comment: added! Thank you

Comment: this looks like the output - what about the input text/column?

Comment: added a fuzzy matching solution that you may be interested in.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, we can define a mapping between matches, then iterate through them and set the column's value, keeping track of columns we've changed. At the end, any columns we never matched get set to `'Other'`.

```
mapping = {'Urolog': 'Urology',
 'Nurse': 'Nurse Practioner',
 'Oncology': 'Oncology',
 'Physician': 'Physician Assistant',
 'Family Medicine': 'Family Medicine',
 'Anesthes': 'Anesthesiology'}

def specialty(column):
    column = column.copy()
    matches = pd.Series(False, index=column.index)
    for k,v in mapping.items():
        match = column.str.contains(k)
        column[match] = v
        matches[match] = True
    column[~matches] = 'Other'
    return column


specialty(df['final_desc'])

39063                Other
50538              Urology
56075       Anesthesiology
36593                Other
51656              Urology
95512                Other
40286       Anesthesiology
3887                 Other
40161                Other
52905       Anesthesiology
35418              Urology
35934                Other
3389                 Other
136                  Other
105460               Other
52568              Urology
24725      Family Medicine
34838                Other
31908     Nurse Practioner
36115                Other
Name: final_desc, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate directly using the index :

```
ix = df[df.desc.str.contains('Urolog')].index
df.loc[ix, 'desc_clean'] = "Urology"
```

So iterating would be something like :

```
dict_specialties = {"Urolog":"Urology",}
for key, val in dict_specialties.items():
  ix = df[df.desc.str.contains(key)].index
  df.loc[ix, 'desc_clean'] = val
```

Answer (score 0):

x received by specialty function is string itself. So no x.str and since it is string you can use 'in' to check as below. Modified some data to see the result
Tip: You should use a dictionary or list rather than using the elif chain.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def specialty(x):
    print(x)
    if x in 'Urolog':
        return 'Urology'
    elif x in 'Nurse':
        return 'Nurse Practioner'
    elif x in 'Oncology':
        return 'Oncology'
    elif x in 'Physician':
        return 'Physician Assistant'
    elif x in 'Family Medicine':
        return 'Family Medicine'
    elif x in 'Anesthes':
        return 'Anesthesiology'
    else:
        return 'Other'
            
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'person_id': {39063: 33081476009, 50538: 33033519093, 56075: 33170508793, 36593: 33061707789, 51656: 33047685345, 95512: 33022026049, 40286: 33038034707, 3887: 33076466195, 40161: 33052807819, 52905: 33190526939, 35418: 33008425164, 35934: 33015737122, 3389: 33055125864, 136: 33139641318, 105460: 33113871389, 52568: 33075745388, 24725: 33052090907, 34838: 33205449839, 31908: 33183672635, 36115: 33006692696}, 
'final_desc': {39063: 'None', 50538: 'Urolog', 56075: 'Anesthes', 36593: 'None', 51656: 'Urology', 95512: 'None', 40286: 'Anesthes', 3887: 'Specialist', 40161: 'None', 52905: 'Anesthesiology', 35418: 'Urology', 35934: 'None', 3389: 'Ophthalmology', 136: 'Rheumatology', 105460: 'None', 52568: 'Urology', 24725: 'Family Medicine', 34838: 'None', 31908: 'Nurse', 36115: 'None'}})

df['desc_clean'] = df['final_desc'].apply(specialty)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
          person_id       final_desc        desc_clean
39063   33081476009             None             Other
50538   33033519093           Urolog           Urology
56075   33170508793         Anesthes    Anesthesiology
36593   33061707789             None             Other
51656   33047685345          Urology             Other
95512   33022026049             None             Other
40286   33038034707         Anesthes    Anesthesiology
3887    33076466195       Specialist             Other
40161   33052807819             None             Other
52905   33190526939   Anesthesiology             Other
35418   33008425164          Urology             Other
35934   33015737122             None             Other
3389    33055125864    Ophthalmology             Other
136     33139641318     Rheumatology             Other
105460  33113871389             None             Other
52568   33075745388          Urology             Other
24725   33052090907  Family Medicine   Family Medicine
34838   33205449839             None             Other
31908   33183672635            Nurse  Nurse Practioner
36115   33006692696             None             Other
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library like `fuzzywuzzy` for fuzzy string matching.  The benefit of this approach is it is more flexible than some rule set, as demonstrated below.

This solution generates the max score of substrings and candidate categories, returning the one that matches best.  If it's below the threshold it will return the default value ("None"):

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

CATEGORIES = [
 'Urology',
 'Nurse Practioner',
 'Oncology',
 'Physician Assistant',
 'Family Medicine',
 'Anesthesiology',
 'Specialist',
]    


def best_match(
    text, 
    categories=CATEGORIES, 
    default="None", 
    threshold=65
):
    matches = {fuzz.partial_ratio(cat, text): cat for cat in categories}
    best_score = max(matches)
    best_match = matches[best_score]
    if best_score >= threshold:
        return best_match
    else:
        return default


df["final_desc"] = df.desc.apply(best_match)
```

result:

```
         person_id           final_desc                     desc
52568  33075745388              Urology                urologist
36593  33061707789     Nurse Practioner         nruse practition
136    33139641318           Specialist      oncology specialist
50538  33033519093  Physician Assistant    physicians assistant
3389   33055125864      Family Medicine            fam. medicine
51656  33047685345       Anesthesiology           anesthesiology
35418  33008425164       Anesthesiology         anesthesiologist
52905  33190526939     Nurse Practioner      Nurses practitioner
36115  33006692696           Specialist  Occupational specialist
31908  33183672635             Oncology               Oncologist
```